# Adding items to another Modules Admin form

Tags: routes, hooks, theming

I have a module that I need to add a few items to, I was told that using hook_form_alter was
the best way to do this, but have been completely unable to get anything to work. Maybe some
one could help me out on it a bit....

The PURPOSE of this enhancement is to add text and links to a login modal, but that's unimportant
at the minute.

The code that I have in my module atm is just to show the form I'm trying to alter

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */

function [modulename]_enhancements_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $form['modal_window'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Modal text and links'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => 0,
    '#weight' => -399,
  );

    $form['modal_window']['login'] = array(
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#format' => 'plain_text',
      '#title' => t('Login text'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('[modulename]_login_text', '[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis a arcu et sem pharetra consectetur. Proin eget lectus neque, quis suscipit lectus. Nullam dictum, massa at sodales porttitor, mi nisi fermentum magna, eu suscipit dui. ]'),
    );

    $form['modal_window']['registration'] = array(
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#format' => 'plain_text',
      '#title' => t('Registration text'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('[modulename]_registration_text', '[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis a arcu et sem pharetra consectetur. Proin eget lectus neque, quis suscipit lectus. Nullam dictum, massa at sodales porttitor, mi nisi fermentum magna, eu suscipit dui.]'),
    );
}
?>


The module has something like this going on with it
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function [modulename]_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/services/[modulename]'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'title' => '[modulename] Settings',
    'access arguments' => array('administer [modulename]'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('[modulename]_admin_form'),
    'description' => '[modulename] Configuration.',
    'file' => '[modulename].admin.inc',
  );
?>

and here's the [modulename].admin.inc
<?php
/**
 * Form builder for the [modulename] administration form.
 */
function [modulename]_admin_form($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user, $base_path;
  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . 'modules/user/user.pages.inc';
  module_load_include('inc', '[modulename]');
  $capabilities = [modulename]_get_capabilities();
  $form = array();

   $form['[modulename]_debug'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('[modulename] debuging'),
    '#description' => t('Write errors to watchdog'),
    '#default_value'=> variable_get('[modulename]_debug', 0),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => -401,
  );
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried? Hook form alter should work fine. Is this D7 or D6? If you really just want to add some text, you can always just theme it, or you want the user to be able to customize the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, let's say that your custom module is named CUSTOMMODULE, and the one you want to alter is ALTERTHIS.

You can use [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter) like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for ALTERTHIS_admin_form().
 */
function CUSTOMMODULE_form_ALTERTHIS_admin_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Alter the $form here.
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the form id, you can use `hook_form_alter()` to easily get a list of all the form id's on a given page too. From there it's usually pretty easy to guess which one is the one you want.

Comment: I ended up with function [modulename]_enhancements_form_[modulename]_admin_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { /* data */